# How to access newly added file in S3 bucket using python

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am new to aws I access files in S3 using python I need to access newly added files in the bucket. Instead of accessing every data present in the bucket. Can anyone help me to reslove this issue?. Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "need to access newly added files"?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at S3 [event notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html). You can have all new files be sent to an SQS queue and have your python program read from the queue to get new files. There is not a way to query S3 for new files. Or if you could create a lambda function to operate on new files as well depending on what you need to do with new files.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a lambda with your business logic in python and finally you create an event in s3:

1. Enter S3 bucket
2. Select "Properties" tab
3. Advance settign section -> Events

[image]

4. New Event:

[image]

*Important: You must have the lambda created.*

**Diagram:**

[image]